# Clear fields after success

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a page with 2 input type=text..

```
@model MVC3.ViewModel.TalkToUsVM

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <ul>
        <li>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TalkToUsRequest.Name)</li>
        <li>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TalkToUsRequest.Email)</li>
    </ul>

    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
}
```

in my controller I do this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(TalkToUsRequest talkToUsRequest)
{
    var vm = new TalkToUsVM();

    if (TryValidateModel(talkToUsRequest))
    {
        vm.Result = "Success";

        return View("Create",vm);
    }

    vm = new TalkToUsVM
    {
        Result = "Errrooooooor",
        TalkToUsRequest = talkToUsRequest
    };

    return View(vm);
}
```

so the problem.. when my model is valid, I set the result to "Success" and in this point vm.TalkToUsRequest is null.. but when page is rendered, all fields are with the same value that when I submited.. even I setting vm.TalkToUsRequest = null!!
How can I clear this fields?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

So in this scenario you have to clear your model state if you return back to the same view.
Try following:

```
    ModelState.Clear();
    return View(vm);
}
```

Comment: Nice.. but why it happens if I'm setting null to TalkToUsRequest?

Comment: That is the default behavior. In your view your MVC helper controls renders new value if it identifies that your model state was changed. Imagine a scenario, where you would click submit button on a form. Which would hit an action on controller. You will do some validation and if things failed then you go back to same view with some error. In that case you want to keep the model values in tact and show some error messages. And if validation passes on controller then you would redirect to some other page.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer :

```
TryUpdateModel(yourmodelname);
```

and it will update your view state

and if you also want to clear all Modelstate.error at the same time you can
also use :

```
 ModelState.Clear();
```