# asp.net core 2.1 model binding (after submit)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have experience with asp.net but  I'm new in .net core so when I tried to perform the simple submit task I got the strange behavior.
When I'm opening the view and sending some model to it  the binding works fine but after i submit this form and try to return empty model or change the value of the passed model binding not working....it keep the value that was submitted.

View

```
 @model EmailModel


    <div class="w3-col m6 w3-panel">
        <div class="w3-large w3-margin-bottom">
            <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-fw w3-hover-text-black w3-xlarge w3-margin-right"></i> Rzemieślnicza 26, 30-403 Kraków, POL<br>
            <i class="fa fa-phone fa-fw w3-hover-text-black w3-xlarge w3-margin-right"></i> Telefon: 667 071 064<br>
            <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw w3-hover-text-black w3-xlarge w3-margin-right"></i> Email: mail@mail.com<br>
        </div>
        <p>Jeżeli masz jakieś pytania, zastrzeżenia lub wątpliwości napisz do nas</p>
        <p>  <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span></p>
        <p>  <span asp-validation-for="EmailTo" class="text-danger"></span></p>
        <p>  <span asp-validation-for="Phone" class="text-danger"></span></p>
        <p>  <span asp-validation-for="Subject" class="text-danger"></span></p>
        <p>  <span asp-validation-for="Text" class="text-danger"></span></p>
        @using (@Html.BeginForm("Contacts", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {

            <div class="w3-row-padding" style="margin:0 -16px 8px -16px">
                <div class="w3-third">

                    <input asp-for="Name" class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Imię i Nazwisko" required>
                </div>
                <div class="w3-third">

                    <input asp-for="EmailTo" class="w3-input w3-border" placeholder="Email" required />

                </div>
                <div class="w3-third">

                    <input asp-for="Phone" class="w3-input w3-border" type="tel" placeholder="Telefon" required />

                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="width:100%">

                <input asp-for="Subject" class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Temat wiadomości" required>

            </div>

            <textarea asp-for="Text" class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Temat wiadomości" required rows="6"></textarea>

            <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-right w3-section" type="submit">
                <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Wyślij wiadomość
            </button>
        }

</div>
```

Model

```
public class EmailModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string EmailTo { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Phone]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Actions

```
   public IActionResult Contacts()
    {
        ViewData["Title"] = _translation["Contacts"];

        return View(new EmailModel() { Name = "Test" });
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Contacts(EmailModel model)
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("Contacts", model);
        }
        try
        {
            string mailBodyhtml = "Imię i Nazwisko: " + model.Name + "<br>" + "Telefon: " + model.Phone + "<br>" + "Email: " + model.EmailTo + "<br><br>" + model.Text;
            var msg = new MailMessage("******", "******", "ZD -"+ model.Subject, mailBodyhtml);
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("******", 587); //if your from email address is "from@hotmail.com" then host should be "smtp.hotmail.com"
            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("***", "*****"); 
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpClient.Send(msg);
            Console.WriteLine("Email Sended Successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
        model.Name = "After submit name";

        return View("Contacts" ,model);
    }
```

1. On first view load `Name ="Test"`
2. On before submit `Name ="My submit name"`
3. After submit  should be  `Name = "After submit name"` but it's s`till ="My submit name"`

However after submit in the debug  `Model.Name ="After submit name"`

Comment: put a breakpoint in your if(!ModelState.IsValid), and make sure it's not just returning the model that is sent in. *edit - I just saw the "However" - so it's probably not the case. Is the page reloading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finaly found what I was looking for . The solution is to use `ModelState.Clear();`

**1)**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Contacts(EmailModel model)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View("Contacts", model);
    }
   ///some code
   ModelState.Clear();
    return View("Contacts", new EmailModel() );
}
```

And If we need to replace only partial view ( for example ajax request):

**2)**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Contacts(EmailModel model)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return PartialView("Contacts", model);
    }
   ///some code
   ModelState.Clear();
    return PartialView("Contacts", new EmailModel() );
}
```

Sorce: [Clear fields after success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855021/clear-fields-after-success)

Comment: Neat alternative to the Post-Redirect-Get pattern. You will still need to watch out for a form re-submission if the user refreshes the page.

Comment: In first  option YES this is just example , in second NO because partial  is replaced by ajax. 
In my case I 'm using ajax submite solution

Answer (score 2):

The values displayed in the view come from `ModelState`, not the model. `ModelState` is composed of values from `Request`, `ViewData`/`ViewBag`, and *finally* `Model`. Since you've already posted, that means there's now a value for `Name` in `Request`, which will then take precedence over anything you set on your model.

While there's some hacky ways around this, the most appropriate path is to follow the PRG (Post-Redirect-Get) pattern. Essentially, after posting, you only return the view again if there's validation errors (in which case, you *want* the posted values to be redisplayed, so the user can make necessary corrections). Otherwise, you redirect - even if you redirect to the same action. The sheer act of redirection causes a new GET request to be issued, and has the effect of resetting the page as if it's the first load - where the values in your model *will* apply.

Comment: And what about ajax requests  when after ajax submit we want to get clear form or sometimes form with calculated values ?

Comment: That has nothing to do with any of this. If you're doing a submit via AJAX, the server is no longer involved in actually determine how the fields are rendered or with what values. If you need to clear the form, you'd do what you'd always do in any situation and literally clear the form via JavaScript, i.e. set the values of each input element to blank, call `form.reset()`, update the values on your client-side model in a two-way data-binding setup, etc. However, this all occurs client-side.

Comment: Thanks for theoretical knowledge but i finally found solutions that i was looking for and answer to my question by myself

Answer (score 2):

As Chris Pratt suggests, the Post-Redirect-Get pattern is appropriate.

Here is one way to achieve that (with a simplified version of your code). Store the updated model in [`TempData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.1#tempdata) before calling `RedirectToAction`.

```
// using Newtonsoft.Json;

public IActionResult Contacts()
{
    var model = new EmailModel { Name = "Test" };

    if (TempData[nameof(EmailModel)] is string json)
    {
        model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmailModel>(json);
    }

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Contacts(EmailModel model)
{
    model.Name = "After submit name";
    TempData[nameof(EmailModel)] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);

    return RedirectToAction("Contacts");
}
```

Since `TempData` stores data only until it's read, it is particularly appropriate for redirection.

Comment: Thanks for your solution , it work's fine but i finalny found solution that i was looking for .Please look into my answer.